# Remove/Add parent element if class is/isn't active on another element but keep the children

Tags: javascript

How would I remove multiple parents but keep in the children elements if an "active" class exists on another element, then add them back in once the "active" class is removed? No jQuery, please. Any help is appreciated.

```js
parentElement = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');

if (document.querySelector(".otherelement").classList.contains("activeclass")) {
  parentElement.forEach(parent => {
    parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="otherelement activeclass">
  ...
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">c1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">c2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">c3</div>
</div>
```

**Edit #1**

Here's what removes the parents

```
// this works
if (document.querySelector(".otherelement").classList.contains("activeclass")) {
  parentElement.forEach(parent => {
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while(parent.firstChild) {
        fragment.appendChild(parent.firstChild);
    }
    parent.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, parent);
  });
} else { // this does not
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.forEach(wrap => {
        child.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, child);
        wrap.appendChild(child);
    });
}
```

**Edit #2 Solution**

Thanks to NcXNaV. Here's how to toggle a parent element. This time with an addEventListener :)

```
addRemoveParent();

let toggleParent = document.getElementById('toggleparent'),
        element = document.getElementsByClassName('otherelement');

toggleParent.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
    if (!element[i].classList.contains('activeclass')) {
      element[i].classList.add('activeclass');
    }
    else element[i].classList.remove('activeclass');
  }
  addRemoveParent();
});

function addRemoveParent(){
  let parentElement = document.querySelectorAll('.parent'),
            childElement = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
  if (document.querySelector('.otherelement').classList.contains('activeclass')) {
    parentElement.forEach(parent => {
      let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
      while(parent.firstChild) {
          fragment.appendChild(parent.firstChild);
      }
      parent.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, parent);
    });
  }
  else {
    childElement.forEach(child => {
      let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.classList.add('parent');
      let parent = child.parentNode;
      parent.replaceChild(wrapper, child);
      wrapper.appendChild(child);
    });
  }
}
```

```
<div class="otherelement"> ... </div>
<div class="child">c1</div>
<div class="child">c2</div>
<div class="child">c3</div>
<button id="toggleparent">Add/Remove 'Active'</button>
```

Comment: Unclear why you want to remove the actual element if you're going to conditionally add it back. Wouldn't it be much easier to show/hide using css?

Comment: It is working so what else do you want?

Comment: I've updated my question for clarity @Kinglish It's for a carousel. CSS animation-fill-mode: forwards; is stopping a hover transition, so I had to wrap the element in a div but the div is now stopping the carousel from working. If I remove the parent element of said div while the carousel is open, it works.

Comment: @decpk It does work, but it removes the child elements as well. It would need to remove just the parent, then add it back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using DocumentFragment in javascript**

**EDITED**: I've added the code to wrap the child back with parent `div`.

What this code does:

1. If **"active"** class ***exists*** on another element, removes outer `<div class="parent">` while maintaining the child `<div class="child">`.
2. If **"active"** class ***does not exists*** on another element, it **wraps** `<div class="child">` back with its parent `<div class="parent">`.

I've also added a `button` which toggles (add/remove) **'activeclass'** to otherelement.

Let me know if this solved your problem.

```js
addRemoveParent();

function toggleClass(){
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('otherelement');

  for(var i = 0; i < element.length; i++)
  {
    if (!element[i].classList.contains('activeclass')){
      element[i].classList.add('activeclass');
    }
    else element[i].classList.remove('activeclass');
  }
  
  addRemoveParent();
}

function addRemoveParent(){
  parentElement = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
  childElement = document.querySelectorAll('.child');

  if (document.querySelector(".otherelement").classList.contains("activeclass")) {
    parentElement.forEach(parent => {
      //parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);

      var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
      while(parent.firstChild) {
          fragment.appendChild(parent.firstChild);
      }
      parent.parentNode.replaceChild(fragment, parent);
    });
  }

  else {
    childElement.forEach(child => {
      let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      wrapper.classList.add('parent');
      let parent = child.parentNode;
      parent.replaceChild(wrapper, child);
      wrapper.appendChild(child);
    });

  }

}
```

```css
.parent{
 color: blue;
 font-size: 20px;
}





/*.parent:before{
content: "<div class='parent'>";
}
.parent:after{
content: "</div>";
}*/
```

```html
<div class="otherelement">
  ...
</div>

<!-- Wrap Parent -->
<div class="child">c1</div>
<div class="child">c2</div>
<div class="child">c3</div>

<p>Initial State: <b>Not Active</b>. (Wrapped with Parent Div)<br>You can click the button and it will toggle between Active/Not Active.</p>
<button onclick="toggleClass();">Add/Remove 'Active'</button>
```

Comment: Yes, this removes the parents perfectly, thanks! However, I now need to wrap the children back with its parents once the active class is removed. I've updated my question with your answer, plus a concept of wrapping each child again. I will of course add back in the class of "parent" with "classList.add" once I figure it out how to wrap.

Comment: @thx1138 Hey, sorry for the late response. I've updated my answer, added the code to wrap the child back with the parent when `<div class='otherelement'>` does not contain class 'active'.

Comment: Not a problem and your solution works perfectly, many thanks! This actually solved a second issue I was having, but everything is now running smoothly :)

Answer (score 2):

To strip the enclosing divs, set their `outerHTML` to their `innerHTML`. Demonstration below. The last enclosing div isn't removed...

```js
const parentElement = document.querySelectorAll('.parent');
const otherElement = document.querySelector(".otherelement");

if (otherElement.classList.contains("activeclass")) {
  parentElement.forEach(parent => {
    parent.outerHTML = parent.innerHTML
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="otherelement activeclass">
  ...
</div>

<div class="parent" style="color:red">
  <div class="child">c1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="color:red">
  <div class="child">c2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="color:red">
  <div class="child">c3</div>
</div>

<div class="not_the_parent" style="color:red">
  <div class="child">My parent remains, so I remain red</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="otherelement activeclass">
  ...
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">c1</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">c2</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">c3</div>
</div>
```